# Windows Phone 8.1 - 2 server methods first without client certificate and second with cert

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, client-certificates

I have server app with 2 methods. In my mobile app I create certificate request and send by using first server method "https://address/method1" - without using client certificate. In response I receive client cert and I install it. If I call second server method "https://address/method2" I use this client certificate, but on my server I dont received it.

I use "Windows.Web.Http"

After received cert in my app:

```
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.InstallCertificateAsync(certificate, InstallOptions.DeleteExpired);
```

Second call:

```
IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certificates = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);

... //find cert 

var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ClientCertificate = clientCertificate;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriAddress, CreateStringContent(httpRequest.RequestData, httpRequest.ContentHeaders));
```

But received request on server was without cert.

- I try use in first call by using .pfx cert. It was reflected, but it was same in second case although I have used other certificate.
- When I close the app and start again, it call server with certificate correctly. (I mean calling only second server method, because certificate was installed). But I need call first and second method together.

edit:

- I try use 2 ports - example "https://address:443/method1" and "https://address:4443/method2". Certificate was received correctly. But I need only one port.